# Best practice for returning a sum of items from controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a controller that returns a list of invoices like so:

```
public function show()
{
    //list all invoices
    $invoices = DB::table('invoices')
        ->join('contacts','invoices.client_id','=','contacts.id')
        ->join('invoice_items','invoices.id','=','invoice_items.invoice_id')
        ->select('*')
        ->get(); //retrieve approved users
    return View::make('dashboard/invoices/list',
        array('invoices' => $invoices));
}
```

I want to be able to display a sum of the invoice_items tables where the invoice_id corresponds to the invoices.id. What is the best practice for accomplishing this? Should I wrote another method and call it in the blade template? Or is there some more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

You can use `groupBy` and `DB::raw()` method from Eloquent to do your COUNT

```
public function show()
{
    //list all invoices
    $invoices = DB::table('invoices')
        ->join('contacts','invoices.client_id','=','contacts.id')
        ->join('invoice_items','invoices.id','=','invoice_items.invoice_id')
        ->groupBy('invoices.id')
        ->select(
            array('invoices.id', DB::raw('count(*) AS cnt_items'))
        )
        ->get();
    return View::make('dashboard/invoices/list',
        array('invoices' => $invoices));
}
```

Alternatively, I suggest you to use eager-loading http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading